# How to plot a function using piecewise of two variables

Tags: plotting, piecewise

[image: I have attached the equation]

```
f[β_, α_] = Piecewise[
  {{-2*α*β + (2*β^2 + 2* α^2)* ArcTan[α/β] - Pi, β >= 0 && α >= 0}, 
  {(-1*5)*(α*β) + (β^2/2 + α^2)* ArcTan[(2* α)/β] - Pi, β <= 0 && α >= 0}}
 ]
```

Can someone help to get the plot for the following closed equation. I Have Tried to solve this using piecewise but not Able to figure right plot.I obtained plot in 3D,Contourplot and Manipulate

Comment: Please provide a copyable code with your `Piecewise` implementation.

Comment: f[\[Beta]_, \[Alpha]_] = 
 Piecewise[{{-2*\[Alpha]*\[Beta] + (2*\[Beta]^2 + 2*\[Alpha]^2)*
      ArcTan[\[Alpha]/\[Beta]] - 
     Pi, \[Beta] >= 0 && \[Alpha] >= 
      0}, {(-1*5)*(\[Alpha]*\[Beta]) + (\[Beta]^2/2 + \[Alpha]^2)*
      ArcTan[(2*\[Alpha])/\[Beta]] - Pi, 
         \[Beta] <= 0 && \[Alpha] >= 0}}]

Comment: Please make an edit to your question instead of adding comments.

Comment: is there anything written wrong

Comment: `ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, Contours -> {0}, 
 ContourShading -> None]`?

Answer (score 2):

```
f[b_, a_] = 
 Piecewise[{{-2*a*b + (2*b^2 + 2*a^2)*ArcTan[a/b] - Pi, 
    b >= 0}, {-5*a*b + (b^2/2 + a^2)*ArcTan[2*a/b] - Pi, b < 0}}]

Plot3D[f[a, b], {a, 0, 10}, {b, -5, 5}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Alpha]", "\[Beta]", ""}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thank you, but can you make it as a simple 2D plot

Comment: What do you mean by 2D - ContourPlot[]?